# How to call the method from component to shared service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have an angular application that I need to show the data based on the entered value

I am able to show the data in one component path is `components/platform/annotation-my-task/annotation-pm-admin-list`

In the above component I have created one method to call the API (by passing some payload) and fetched the data, and it is working fine.

**annotation-pm-admin-list**

```
getDetails(){
//here subscribed  the api and fetched the data
}
```

Now I need the same details in other component `components/platform/annotation/annotation-process-list`

So if I call the same API from the above component by creating the shared service it is not working.(because In API call we have passed some values which re accessed from other components)

So I am thinking to share the same method from annotation-pm-admin-list.ts to shared service and shard service to my other component, I don't know whether it is correct

What am I doing wrong? I am very new to angular and I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you need sharing between the components should be in the service.

In your case, I believe it is the data filter from `annotation-pm-admin-list`.

1. Add a [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) to your Service to store the filter (so the last value is retained);
2. add methods/variables to your service to allow storing/accessing the filter and to perform the request from the stored filter:

```
  filter$ = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<YourFilterModel>>({})

  getData() {
      return this.filter$.pipe(
          take(1),
          switchMap(filter => this.http.post<YourDataModel>('your-url', filter))
      );
  }
```

3. from the components, when you'd like to update the filter your call

```
 this.yourService.filter$.next({  attr1:'val-1', attr2: 'val2' })
```

4. from the components, when you'd like to receive data (using the last used filter):

```
  data$ = this.yourService.getData()
```

If you'd like to retail the last data received in your service, you could add a second BehaviorSubject to hold it:

```
  filter$ = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<YourFilterModel>>({})
  data$ = new BehaviorSubject<YourDataModel>({})


  constructor(....) { 
    this.filter$.pipe(
          switchMap(filter => this.http.post<YourDataModel>('your-url', filter)
    ).subscribe(data => this.data$.next(data))
  }
```

in this second version, every time the `filter$` variable is changed, a new request will be sent to your API. When it responds the latest data will be stored in the `data$` subject

1. from the components, when you'd like to update the filter your call

```
 this.yourService.filter$.next({  attr1:'val-1', attr2: 'val2' })
```

2. from the components, when you'd like to receive the latest data stored in the service:

```
  data$ = this.yourService.data$
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case  you can use redux store wherein we have to fetch once from api and that can be used in any of the components

There are many other ways to do what you need but redux would be perfect solution and is created for such a thing

If that looks like lot of work to do u can also check on behavior-subject

[BehaviourSubject](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc)